# Replace a line in a config file with ansible

Tags: ansible

I am new to ansible.

Is there a simple way to replace the line starting with `option domain-name-servers` in `/etc/dhcp/interface-br0.conf` with more IPs?

```
  option domain-name-servers 10.116.184.1,10.116.144.1;
```

I want to add `,10.116.136.1`

Comment: [`lineinfile`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/lineinfile_module.html). Use `regexp` and `backrefs` parameters, learn from included examples.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can use the [lineinfile Ansible module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html) to achieve that.

```
  - name: replace line
    lineinfile: 
      path: /etc/dhcp/interface-br0.conf 
      regexp: '^(.*)option domain-name-servers(.*)$' 
      line: 'option domain-name-servers 10.116.184.1,10.116.144.1,10.116.136.1;'
      backrefs: yes
```

The `regexp` option tells the module what will be the content to replace.

The `line` option replaces the previously found content with the new content of your choice.

The `backrefs` option guarantees that if the regexp does not match, the file will be left unchanged.

Comment: What is the backrefs doing in this example?

Comment: should be **path:** instead of **dest:**. [Ansible Docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/lineinfile_module.html#examples)

Answer (score 9):

You can use Replace Module. Please refer to
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/replace_module.html.

```
#example
vim httpd-replace-hostname.yml

---
- hosts: <Your ansible host>
  tasks:
  - name: hostname was used instead of path.
    replace:
      path: /etc/hosts
      regexp: '(\s+)old\.name\.com(\s+.*)?$'
      replace: '\new.name.com\2'
      backup: yes
```

Run

```
ansible-playbook httpd-replace-hostname.yml
```

You can check out the result successfully as below.

```
PLAY [Your hosts] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [hostname.name.com]

TASK [hostname was used instead of path.] ***************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [hostname.name.com]

TASK [Replace after the expression till the end of the file] ********************************************************************************************************************
changed: [hostname.name.com]

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
hostname.name.com : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Answer (score 3):

we can use **lineinfile module** to replace a line

using **ad-hoc command**:

```
ansible <host> -m lineinfile -a "path=/etc/dhcp/interface-br0.conf regexp=''^(.*)option domain-name-servers(.*)$'' line='1option domain-name-servers 10.116.184.1,10.116.144.1,10.116.136.1;' backrefs: yes"
```

using **ansible playbook**:

```
- name: replacing a line in file
  lineinfile: 
    path: /etc/dhcp/interface-br0.conf 
    regexp: '^(.*)option domain-name-servers(.*)$' 
    line: 'option domain-name-servers 10.116.184.1,10.116.144.1,10.116.136.1;'
    backrefs: yes
```

for more we can check for other options: in **lineinfile** module

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/lineinfile_module.html

Answer (score 1):

I created a role `dhcp` with the following `main.yaml`:

```
---
- name: add all dns servers
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/dhcp/interface-br0.conf
    regexp: '^\s*option domain-name-servers.*$'
    line: '  option domain-name-servers 10.116.184.1,10.116.144.1,10.116.136.1;'
    backrefs: yes
  become: true
```

Comment: can we have a replace or add new line if not found