# ANSIBLE How to add IP to existing entries in the string by a regex?

Tags: regex, ansible

There is lineinfile /opt/firewall-rules.sh:

> TESTING="111.111.111.111/32,111.111.111.112/32"

How through the lineinfile module to add to the two existing third ip entry - 111.111.111.113/32, so that as a result the lines look like this:

> TESTING="111.111.111.111/32,111.111.111.112/32,111.111.111.113/32"

There is the particular solution at other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40788575/replace-a-line-in-a-config-file-with-ansible) but it doesn't add one IP it replace whole line.

```html
- name: Firewall rule
  replace:
    path: /opt/firewall-rulles.sh
    regexp: '"$'
    replace: ',111.111.111.113/32"'
    after: 'TEST=*'
    before: 'DEVELOPE*'
    backup: yes
```

I'm trying this but it replace all after DEVELOPE

Solution as I see(**Best regards for all answers and advice**):

```
- name: Firewall rule for DB_TESTING
   replace:
      path: /opt/firewall-rules.sh
      regexp: '(^TESTING=.*)"$'
      replace: '\1,{{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}/32"'
      backup: yes
   delegate_to: DB_TESTING
```

It's adding IP line from host variable at delegated servers firewall config

**Best regards**

Comment: Essentially, you need to replace the last " with ',<IP_ADDRESS>"'. Try looking at the `replace` module. You can match the last  quote with "$ Note: this doesn't take into account what happens if the IP already exists - each time you run the task, the IP address will get added, whether it is already there or not, so you should likely also consider making it conditional.

Comment: thanks for advice I'll trying this

Comment: But there is another problem how to point  only regexp: '^TESTING=(.*)$' line and replace only the last quote?

Comment: - name: Firewall rule
replace:
path: /opt/firewall-rulles.sh
regexp: '"$'
replace: ',111.111.111.113/32"'
after: 'TEST=*'
before: 'DEVELOPE*'
backup: yes

I'm trying this but it replace all after DEVELOPE

Comment: Yeah sorry. My Comment was too brief, however if you check at the bottom of the replace docs, there are plenty of examples. You need to store the contents of the line up to the final quote, to use in the replace. `regexp: '(^TESTING.*)"$'`. `\1` then contains everything that was matched between `()` and can be used in your replace string.

Answer (score 1):

try with this regexp='^(TESTING(?!.*\b,111.111.111.113/32\b).*)$'