# Replace a line in a config file using variables with ansible

Tags: deployment, ansible, configuration

Question is similar to this one: [Replace a line in a config file with ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40788575/replace-a-line-in-a-config-file-with-ansible) . Difference is that my playbook is first copying a file to a destination and then editing that same file after it's been copied. Also I'm using variables to replace the string, however it isn't changing the lines that contain the particular string *site_name* in the conf file.

**Playbook**;

```
---
  - hosts: server-test2
    become: true
    vars:
      site_name: bokucasinon.com
    tasks:
      - name: Configuring nginx for the new site
        template:
          src: ../provision-server/nginx.j2
          dest: /etc/nginx/conf.d/{{site_name}}.conf
          mode: 064
      - name: Configuring nginx for the new site 
        become: true
        lineinfile:
          dest: /etc/nginx/conf.d/{{site_name}}.conf
          regexp: '^(.*)site_name(.*)$'
          line: "{{site_name}}"
          backrefs: yes
```

**Output**:

```
TASK [Configuring nginx for the new site] **************************************************************
task path: /home/melvmagr/repos/ansible/provision-server/wp-db-nginx-conf.yml:10
ok: [server-test2] => {"changed": false, "checksum": "904d19dde94ad38672d751246fd2680ce297244d", "dest": "/etc/nginx/conf.d/bokucasinon.com.conf", "gid": 0, "group": "root", "mode": "0064", "owner": "root", "path": "/etc/nginx/conf.d/bokucasinon.com.conf", "size": 4232, "state": "file", "uid": 0}

TASK [Configuringg nginx for the new site] *************************************************************
task path: /home/melvmagr/repos/ansible/provision-server/wp-db-nginx-conf.yml:15
ok: [server-test2] => {"backup": "", "changed": false, "msg": ""}
META: ran handlers
META: ran handlers

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************
server-test2               : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

As one can see, changed=0 and upon checking the conf file it remains *site_name* instead of *bokucasinon.com*

Another thing I tried was to use the replace module but got same output.

```
 replace: 
   path: /etc/nginx/conf.d/{{site_name}}.conf
   regexp: '(^site_name)(.*)$'
   replace: '{{site_name}}'
```

Any ideas why this is happening or what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: According your description you could already use the template module to provision the edited file. There is absolutly no need to deploy a template, copy it over and edit lines afterwards at the target. Instead it seems to be an anti-pattern in Ansible.

Comment: If you do template the file, the `{{site_name}}` is considered as a variable and replaced. By its value, so you are too late to do a replacement of any sort.

Comment: Trying to do it using only the template module but it gives error; `fatal: [server-test2]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "checksum": "904d19dde94ad38672d751246fd2680ce297244d", "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (ansible.legacy.copy) module: lineinfile. Supported parameters include: group, mode, validate, src, _original_basename, follow, local_follow, selevel, dest, serole, unsafe_writes, checksum, owner, force (thirsty), directory_mode, remote_src, seuser, attributes (attr), backup, content, setype."}` Beginner with ansible here sorry

Comment: `Unsupported parameters for (ansible.legacy.copy)` You are using the `copy` module not the `template` module (and you added `lineinfile` as a parameter to `copy` which is unsupported). Please see the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html)

Comment: [Just to put you on track](https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/047d1402872b7cd6cb2c487138c6e4c1)

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate all of you for the help but I've managed to find what I was looking for, after lots of trials and errors. I did indeed need to use the `ansible.builtin.replace` module. Apparently what I was using (the `lineinfile` module) was not made for changing ALL the lines that contain a particular string (reference: https://www.middlewareinventory.com/blog/ansible-lineinfile-examples/) so basically just to put things into perspective, I needed to change my playbook with the following;

```
  - name: Configuring nginx for the new site
    become: true
    template:
      src: ../provision-server/nginx.j2         
      dest: /etc/nginx/conf.d/{{site_name}}.conf
      mode: 064
  - name: Configuring nginx for the new site 
    become: yes
    become_user: root
    ansible.builtin.replace:
      path: /etc/nginx/conf.d/{{site_name}}.conf
      regexp: 'sitename.com'
      replace: "{{site_name}}"
```