ansible , how to replace and filter json data?
I am trying to write ansible code first time to handle json.
I have a file in my /home/ which has following json data.
here is the input json
  "acl": [
    {
      "browse": true,
      "create": false
    },
    {
      "browse": false,
      "create": true
    }
  ],
  "groups": [
    {
      "name": "abc",
      "location": "texas"
    },
    {
      "name": "def",
      "location": "austin"
    }
  ],
  "users": [
    {
      "name": "admin",
      "description": "administrator",
      "password": "windows2011"
    },
    {
      "name": "testuser",
      "description": "guest",
      "password": "testpassword"
    }
  ]
}


I want to update password of the user in user's object where name is admin
so i that output file has updated password for user admin. the output file should be located in /home/location with _updated.json extension.
the output json should like this
{
  "acl": [
    {
      "browse": true,
      "create": false
    },
    {
      "browse": false,
      "create": true
    }
  ],
  "groups": [
    {
      "name": "abc",
      "location": "texas"
    },
    {
      "name": "def",
      "location": "austin"
    }
  ],
  "users": [
    {
      "name": "admin",
      "description": "administrator",
      "password": "updatedpassword"
    },
    {
      "name": "testuser",
      "description": "guest",
      "password": "testpassword"
    }
  ]
}

ansible code which i have written so far-
---
- name: Update admin user password in JSON file
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: Read the JSON file
      ansible.builtin.command:
        cmd: cat /home/conf.json
      register: json_content

Thank you.

Are you wanting the Ansible script to do the actual updating of the password? Or are you wanting to change the password in the JSON file and then copy the updated file to updated_conf.json? The copy module is really nice for copying files, but the template module is amazing for substituting values in files.

I want to update the password using ansible script


Declare the input file

  input_file: data.json

and read it into a dictionary
    - include_vars:
        file: "{{ input_file }}"
        name: data

gives
  data:
    acl:
    - browse: true
      create: false
    - browse: false
      create: true
    groups:
    - location: texas
      name: abc
    - location: austin
      name: def
    users:
    - description: administrator
      name: admin
      password: windows2011
    - description: guest
      name: testuser
      password: testpassword


Declare the updated users

  users:
    - name: admin
      password: updatedpassword

and merge them
  update: "{{ [data.users, users] | community.general.lists_mergeby('name')
                                  | community.general.dict_kv('users') }}"

gives
  update:
    users:
    - description: administrator
      name: admin
      password: updatedpassword
    - description: guest
      name: testuser
      password: testpassword


Update data

  data_update: "{{ [data, update] | combine }}"

gives
  data_update:
    acl:
    - browse: true
      create: false
    - browse: false
      create: true
    groups:
    - location: texas
      name: abc
    - location: austin
      name: def
    users:
    - description: administrator
      name: admin
      password: updatedpassword
    - description: guest
      name: testuser
      password: testpassword


Declare the output file and write it

    - copy:
        dest: "{{ output_file }}"
        content: |
          {{ data_update | to_nice_json }}
      vars:
        arr: "{{ input_file | splitext | list }}"
        output_file: "{{ arr.0 }}_updated{{ arr.1 }}"

gives what you want
shell> diff data.json data_updated.json 
26c26
<             "password": "windows2011"
---
>             "password": "updatedpassword"



Example of a complete playbook for testing
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    input_file: data.json

    users:
      - name: admin
        password: updatedpassword

    update: "{{ [data.users, users] | community.general.lists_mergeby('name')
                                    | community.general.dict_kv('users') }}"
    data_update: "{{ [data, update] | combine }}"

  tasks:

    - include_vars:
        file: "{{ input_file }}"
        name: data

    - debug:
        var: data
    - debug:
        var: update
    - debug:
        var: data_update

    - copy:
        dest: "{{ output_file }}"
        content: |
          {{ data_update | to_nice_json }}
      vars:
        arr: "{{ input_file | splitext | list }}"
        output_file: "{{ arr.0 }}_updated{{ arr.1 }}"



What you can do is use the template module and use "variable interpolation" to put in the password you wish to use. First update your conf.json file:
{
  "acl": [
    {
      "browse": true,
      "create": false
    },
    {
      "browse": false,
      "create": true
    }
  ],
  "groups": [
    {
      "name": "abc",
      "location": "texas"
    },
    {
      "name": "def",
      "location": "austin"
    }
  ],
  "users": [
    {
      "name": "admin",
      "description": "administrator",
      "password": "{{ admin_password }}"
    },
    {
      "name": "testuser",
      "description": "guest",
      "password": "testpassword"
    }
  ]
}

Then update your Ansible script to replace the variable with the new password:
---
- name: Update admin user password in JSON file
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    admin_password: 'updatedpassword'
  tasks:
    - name: Update the JSON configuration
      ansible.builtin.template:
        src: /home/conf.json
        dest: /home/updated_conf.json

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html
You could also do the same with the testuser account by replacing the password with {{ testuser_password }} and then adding the variable and value to the Ansible script.

it is not possible to use template. the conf.json file will be dynamically put by some another program on this location and then my ansible code is going to read this file and replace the password where name is admin.

Maybe using lineinfile would be helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40788575/replace-a-line-in-a-config-file-with-ansible It isn't parsing JSON or anything, but you can replace the line with the proper password.
